# Consolas font missing in VS2017 Win 7

Tags: visual-c++, fonts, windows-7, consolas

I am working with Win 10 and Win 7.
On both I use the newest version of MSVC 2017.
While working on the Win 10 machine, everything works fine and I can use/select the Consolas font.
When working on the Win 7 machine, everything also works fine, but I can't select Consolas font, because there is no entry for it.

Please tell me how to restore the Consolas font.
I used the "Repair" command on MSVC 2017 Installer, but the font hasn't been installed.
Deleting and reinstalling MSVC 2017 hasn't helped either.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Consolas is not installed by Visual Studio. You need to install it into Windows yourself, or install a product that adds it.

Comment: @Richard it should be [part of Windows since Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas): "It has been included with Windows since Windows Vista,"

Answer (score 0):

Just open `C:\Windows\Fonts`, search for `Consolas`, press Ctrl-C, and then copy to a Windows 7 computer.

Since Windows 11 22H2 you can no longer open that folder. There is still a way if you type in the explorer: `\\localhost\c$\Windows\Fonts`